# Fill SKB and cut firts 8 bytes

Tags: c

Hello i wanted to fill a socked buffer and with a char array and cut off the first 8 bytes. so what i wrote is:

```
stm_tty_receive(struct serdev_device *serdev, const unsigned char *data,
        size_t count)
...
pr_info("data: %s", data);
pr_info("data-cut: %s", &data[8]);
memcpy(skb_put(stm->rx_skb,(count -8)), (void*)&data[8], (count -8));
pr_info("rx_skb: %s",stm->rx_skb->data);
```

But my output looks like this:

```
data: \xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa\xab33
data-cut: 33
rx_skb: `
```

but my rx_skb has not 33 insted it has `.

Comment: Tip: That `void*` is useless.

Comment: Tip: `&data[8]` can be written as `data+8`

Comment: `%s` doesn't make much sense here since I doubt `data` is guaranteed to be NUL-terminated.

Comment: What happens when `count` < 8?

Comment: I would not get so far because i have a checkbefore where i look if the first 8 bytes fit my pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `memcpy` does exactly what you want it to do (assuming the two buffers don't overlap).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void dump(unsigned char *data, size_t count) {
   for (size_t i=0; i<count; ++i)
      printf("%02X ", data[i]);

   printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
   unsigned char data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
   size_t count = 12;
   dump(data, count);

   unsigned char *chopped = malloc(count-8);
   memcpy(chopped, data+8, count-8);   // Or &data[8]
   dump(chopped, count-8);

   free(chopped);
}
```

Output:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C
09 0A 0B 0C
```

This leads one to conclude that your misuse of `%s` is leading to confusion, or `skb_put(stm->rx_skb,(count -8))` and `stm->rx_skb->data` return different pointers.